# Qual è il significato di "agone" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning

Ecco un frammento di una lettera che Vittorio Gassman scrisse a un suo compagno quando stava studiando nella Accademia d'arte drammatica. Il testo appare nel libro autobiografico *Un grande avvenire dietro le spalle*.

> Il prossimo anno non giocherò più. Non che io senta stanchezze o logorii; le gambe rispondono, scattano, «sanno» tutto del gioco. Sanno troppo, ecco il punto; non c'è più mistero, la bambola è sventrata, i congegni svelati. Gioco via via con sempre meno curiosità per l'evento puramente atletico, spio nelle sollecitazioni muscolari, nelle tattiche e nelle combinazioni il ponte analogico con **l'agone teatrale** che ci ha ormai definitivamente ammaliati.

Il brano si riferisce al gioco della pallacanestro, praticato da Gassman quando era giovane.

Non riesco a cogliere il senso dell'espressione "agone teatrale" nel brano precedente. Ho letto tutte le [accezioni del vocabolo "agone" nel vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/agone1/), ma continuo a non capire bene il significato. Sapreste spiegarmelo?

Comment: Vedi *l'agone teatrale* come *la sfida di mostrarsi sul palcoscenico*. In pratica la similitudine è fra la sfida atletica e quella teatrale, la prima ormai priva di interesse e la seconda molto più viva nel pensiero.

Comment: Cerca anche nell'enciclopedia Treccani online

Comment: @ErikvanDoren: L'ho fatto, ma le spiegazioni sono simili a quelle del vocabolario (con più dettagli però).

Comment: “Nome generico di scene della tragedia e della commedia greca” mi sembra si applichi, con il passaggio dalla parte al tutto.

Comment: @N74: Potresti scriverlo come risposta?

Comment: Fatto come da richiesta ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vedi l'*agone teatrale* come *la sfida di mostrarsi sul palcoscenico*.

In pratica la similitudine è fra la sfida atletica e quella teatrale, la prima ormai priva di interesse e la seconda molto più viva nel pensiero.